# Why does String.equalsIgnoreCase compare both upper-, AND lower-case versions of individual characters?

Tags: java, string, comparison, uppercase, lowercase

I was looking into de-compiled sources of Java SE7 String class, in particular at the equalsIgnoreCase method, and what struck me as odd was the following line (performed in a while loop, local vars omitted):

```
if (((c1 = this.value[(o1++)]) != (c2 = target[(o2++)])) 
    && (toUpperCase(c1) != toUpperCase(c2)) 
    && (toLowerCase(c1) != toLowerCase(c2))) { 
        return false; 
}
```

And I wondered why the c1 and c2 are checked for non-equality in both, upper- and lower-case forms. Surely if the uppercase comparison was equal, the lowercase would never even be reached... from this, however, i am led to believe that there are cases when uppercase(c1)!=uppercase(c2) AND the characters are still equal when compared in lower-case.

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Could it be that some non-latin characters compare equal upper-case and not lower-case, or vice-versa? Good question anyway.

Comment: @Mena - Actually it is not good.  1) It is a duplicate. 2) The answer is in the source code comments, and the source code is freely available from a number of places.

Comment: @StephenC Oops. Should have done my homework.

Answer (score 2):

From [this link](http://coding.tocea.com/tools/pmd/uselocalewithcaseconversions/) there seem to be Locales where some upper- and lowercases don't match. The example used is turkish where

```
if (x.toLowerCase().equals("list"))
```

will not return true for `x="LIST"`.

I would suspect that there are several such cases therefore the options are either to specify the locale which seems to have to potential to produce a lot of other hiccups or compare both cases. So basically there are examples where letters can be the same in one case and not the other

Answer (score 2):

The real Java source code for `equalsIgnoreCase` is as follows:

```
public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString) {
    return (this == anotherString) ? true
            : (anotherString != null)
            && (anotherString.value.length == value.length)
            && regionMatches(true, 0, anotherString, 0, value.length);
}
```

The code you are talking about is in `regionMatches`, and here is the relevant section, complete with the original comments:

```
        if (ignoreCase) {
            // If characters don't match but case may be ignored
            // try converting both characters to uppercase.
            // If the results match, then the comparison scan should
            // continue.
            char u1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
            char u2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
            if (u1 == u2) {
                continue;
            }
            // Unfortunately, conversion to uppercase does not work properly
            // for the Georgian alphabet, which has strange rules about case
            // conversion.  So we need to make one last check before
            // exiting.
            if (Character.toLowerCase(u1) == Character.toLowerCase(u2)) {
                continue;
            }
        }
```

**Lesson:**  Don't waste your time looking at decompiled code when the actual source code is freely available ... as it is for the Java libraries.  In fact, the source code for the Java libraries has been included in JDKs for as long as I can remember looking for it.

References:

- http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/String.java#String.equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29
- http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/String.java#String.regionMatches%28boolean%2Cint%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Cint%29
- If the above URLs / links stop working, Google for `"java.lang.String" source` and you will see other places to view the source on the interwebs.